# how to do LightAutoML data preprocessing especially NaN Values

Tags: python

Hi I am using LightAutoML on supervised data can someone help me with how to do preprocessing in this framework I am using it for the first time
I have tried to use train split but it says that input contains null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out in the documentation of lightautoml that it takes care of data preprocessing and feature engineering too

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).